# Unity White line on editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't get rid of these white lines one the Unity 2017 editor. Does anyone know a solution?

[image]

Comment: Just to check, you are referring to the white **blocks**, right?

Comment: Yes I found a solution by installing windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Windows 7 and everything is working fine. I guess there was an issue With the graphics card support (AMD). Thanks to everyone for your help

Answer (score 3):

Select the Gizmos drop down and uncheck "Show Grid"[image]